# Is there a tool to have git show "detached heads" in a graph?

Tags: git

I often refer to `git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all --full-history` to see the current state of my branches, but it does not show detached heads/anonymous branches. Is there a way to get detached heads to appear in this graph?

I know that `git reflog` exists, but that is pretty hard to read since there is no structure - all you have to go on is the commit message, which still may be WIP if I haven't finished the commit yet.

Some background (this is not necessary to answer the question, but will help explain the motivation for it): I'm a Mercurial user and my workflow involves a lot of anonymous branching. I tend to make use of `hg heads` a lot to check out these heads, and often `hg rebase` to separate or combine series of commits based on what makes sense for the purpose of an easy to understand code review.

While I'm getting used to using git I often find myself with detached heads when, for example, I rebase some commits from a branch to make a new branch. Finding these detached heads is annoying with `git reflog`, and to be honest it's a little scary that they just disappear from the usual `git log`. I've even forgotten about old commits this way, and have had to dig them out of `git reflog` a day or two later. In Mercurial those commits would remain as an anonymous head, and I would be reminded that I need to finish them off.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to use a workflow that doesn't quite match the way git works.

First of all, a "detached head" in git isn't the same as Mercurial's concept of a "head". Git has exactly one HEAD, which is just the currently checked-out commit. "Detached" just means that you don't currently have a branch checked out. So when you create a commit, it won't be associated with a branch, and it'll be lost when you checkout a different commit.

In Git, every commit that you care about should be reachable from some branch. There's no such thing as an "anonymous branch", which is why git warns you when committing on a detached head. Committing on a detached head is like allocating an object and then throwing away the pointer; it's possible, but almost never what you want to do. Remember, branches in git are lightweight and can be ephemeral. Just create a branch before committing so that you can find your commits again.

All that being said, if you really want to see the structure of your repository, including commits that are only referenced from reflogs, you can use:

```
git log --graph --decorate $(git rev-list -g --all)
```

Comment: It sounds lazy, but having to think of a name for a branch in advance is annoying. Then I have to delete the name later on, too. That doesn't sound lightweight to me. I wonder if there's an extension that will maintain pointers to every unnamed branch for me. Then I could rename the branch if I decide to keep it, or delete it if I want to let it be GCed.

Comment: @dmnd You have the Latin alphabet to ease your life. When you want to branch, do `git checkout -b a`. It will create a branch named `a` which is very much like an anonymous branch because its name is absolutely useless. If you run out of letters this way, you're doing something git wasn't designed for. Perhaps you could mention in your question how exactly you keep track of your work if you don't name branches. Are you inspecting commit messages regularly? People also tend to use aliases, so you could abbreviate the above to `gco -b a`. You still need to use a unique name for a branch though.

Comment: I'm not aware of such an extension, but it sounds straightforward. Replace "git commit" with a shell script that first tests whether HEAD is detached (by checking the exit status of `git symbolic-ref HEAD`) and, if so, creates a new branch using whatever naming scheme you like.

Comment: Thanks for the tip David, I think I'll try that. I'll also need to autobranch the commits that are left behind after an interactive rebase. (In Mercurial, rebase 'moves' commits, but any you leave behind stick around. In git it seems they are copied, but the old ones are hidden, even ones you decided not to move.)

Comment: Yep, AFAIK git never removes commits through any mechanism other than garbage collection.

Comment: @dmnd FYI, there is no such thing as an "unnamed branch". Detached heads are not tracked, and are considered garbage waiting to be collected (discarded). If you want to track commits, you need to tag them or put them in branches.

Comment: Yeah, I can understand why git is hiding these detached heads by default now. There's a lot of rebase 'shadows' lying around because rebase copies rather than moves.

Comment: I use tags instead of branches before very tricky rebases - e.g. `git tag hold` - it's not ultimately very different than creating a branch, but it feels simpler and less important somehow.

Comment: @David, I like your answer, but I think you should add something about garbage collection (in the answer, not just your comment above) to emphasize how incredibly dangerous this workflow is.

Comment: add `--since=am` to the `git log` command and you see *all* commits of only today

Comment: So I was doing a particularly tricky rebase and wanted to find my `branch` HEAD before I started rebasing on an updated `master`. I had to read through 3 paragraphs of criticism without knowing if this answer would be useful, before you showed the command allowing me to find a commit of my old `branch` which forked off my "old `master`".

Comment: Is there a way to add this in `.gitconfig` `[alias]` section? getting an error with the revlist part

Comment: @neaumusic Add this to your `.gitconfig [alias]` section: `logd = !bash -c 'git log --graph --decorate $(git rev-list -g --all)'`

Comment: git log --graph  --decorate --reflog better and simpler )

Comment: @David It does seem iteresting though that putting the options in the inverse order didn't show the dangling commit for me. I just reset the commit and had it hanging right after the current HEAD. Doing `git log --graph --decorate $(git rev-list --all --walk-reflogs)` didn't show it, while `git log --graph --decorate $(git rev-list --walk-reflogs --all)` did. Any idea why?

Answer (score 22):

You want `git fsck --lost-found`

It will give you the dangling commits (not on a branch).

Output will look something like this:

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
dangling blob 18bcff3c8741a2cf2522f29e90570efec46b32a6
dangling blob 98ea60e43e9ec74b5e4a6b9bee774fc39be2feed
dangling blob bdd4824eb73f39327afd191fb704a0380963384a
dangling blob 45a99326deead9d436ff6b54d7e40b3d8b16c4b2
dangling commit 488bc730f09ceba206331660ecb1f9156f5ae594
dangling commit d3c35fc70085c3c25b916073554ab631bdb8b11c
dangling commit ee99e7a0e2fe2e34a68a19ca76f623274edc2ab6
```

Afterwards, get more info with `git show` -- example: `git show d3c3`

You can get info on the "blob" also which may have been a staged change from a merge conflict but was never committed. Helpful for recovering lost data.

The answer above using `git log` is fantastic also, btw.

Comment: I found `git cat-file -p <object>` also extremely helpful to find the parent of dangling objects.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an alternative tool like [Jujutsu](https://github.com/martinvonz/jj) or [Sapling](https://sapling-scm.com/), both of which center anonymous head-based workflows. Both tools work with Git repos, though only Jujutsu can have a ["colocated Git repo"](https://github.com/martinvonz/jj/blob/main/docs/git-compatibility.md#co-located-jujutsugit-repos) which would let it work most of the time with Git-centric tooling.

(I was a major contributor to Sapling in the past, though I prefer and use Jujutsu full-time these days.)