# format git log to get full commit graph view (even with detached head)

Tags: git

I intend to execute `git log --raw --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h %Creset%s %Cgreen%d%n%aN %Cblue(%ah)%Creset%n%b' $(git rev-list -g --all)` when I type `git log`. but I do not want to make a `bash` alias for the same. Is there a way to do it just with `git` functionality?

P.S. I found the `$(git rev-list -g --all)` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16368880).

This is my current `.gitconfig` file.

```
...
...

[log]
    abbrevCommit = true
    follow = true
[format]
    pretty = oneline
[alias]
    LOG = log --raw --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h %Creset%s %Cgreen%d%n%aN %Cblue(%ah)%Creset%n%b'

...
...
```

I can not directly add the `$(git rev-list -g --all)` in alias, as it gives an error.

Also, making an alias for `LOG` is just a workaround I had to adopt as I was unable to change the default `log` behavior.

P.S. I understand that `$()` is a bash functionality, but I mean, is there something else that can get me the desired output.

Sorry if my English is off, I am a non-native speaker.

Edit:
I am now using `LOG = !~/.local/bin/git-log` for my alias, where the file has this line in it `git log --raw --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h %Creset%s %Cgreen%d%n%aN %Cblue(%ah)%Creset%n%b' $(git rev-list -g --all)`

I found it in [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aolI_Rz0ZqY&t=468s) by the co-founder of GitHub.

I haven't marked it solved as this approach is still using bash, and not native `git` functionality.

Comment: You can use both `-g` and `--all` in `git log`, so that you don't have to call `git rev-list`.

Comment: @ElpieKay but I can not use `--graph` with `-g --all` as it gives this error: `fatal: cannot combine --walk-reflogs with history-limiting options` Also, upon using `-g --all` with `git LOG` without `--graph`, I get undesired output (It has the same commits, which are predecessors of HEAD, repeated multiple times).

Comment: `LOG = "!git log --raw --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h %Creset%s %Cgreen%d%n%aN %Cblue(%ah)%Creset%n%b' $(git rev-list -g --all)"` should work. (and no, you cannot replace builtin commands with a custom alias)

Comment: @IshaanKapoor I didn't know that `--graph` and `-g` cannot work together. The output of `git rev-list` might cause the command to a bash error `Argument list too long`.